# Can i use UUID as datatype for id field in model/pojo class using hibernate search

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I am trying to implement search functionality using hibernate search for my project which is in spring boot .

I used hibernate search annotations like `@Indexed`, `@Field`.

When i use datatype of id  Field as Long then search is performed and list of results is returned but in my project UUID is used as datatype for id field which is also primary key  .in the case of UUID the result is an empty list.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;
```

How can i perform search operation using UUID as datatype for id field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following code

```
@Id
@Type(type = "uuid-char") // add column type
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
```

You need to add  **@Type** for the ID column if your using uuid as your data type

I hope it helps you 
Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you @Surjeet Singh Rathore

Comment: thank u @sridhar sir it is helpful. now getting list of data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `UUID` as a document ID, and it should work out of the box.

If you're not getting any result:

- Check you're using a recent version of Hibernate Search (5.11+) and Hibernate ORM (5.4+).
- Check that you reindexed your data after changing the type of your ID.
- When reindexing, check your logs for indexing failures and report them here.
- Test with a very simple query, for example `qb.all().createQuery()`. If you get results with that query, the problem is with your initial query, not with your identifier.

You can apply [@sridhar-karuppusamy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62158887/6692043), but that should only be necessary if you want the database type to be `VARCHAR` instead of `VARBINARY`. And that is irrelevant to Hibernate Search.